# Mongodb : count array values with mapreduce / aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have documents with the following structure :

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "items" : [
       {"key1" : "value1"},
       {"key1" : "value1"}
    ]
}
```

And have built a simple function to count the number of "items" total.

```
var count = 0;
db.collection.find({},{items:1}).limit(10000).forEach(
    function (doc) {
        if(doc.items){
               count += doc.items.length;
        }
    }
)
print(count);
```

But after ~1 million items, my function breaks, Mongo exits. I've looked at the new aggregation framework as well as mapreduce functions, and I'm not sure which would be the best to use for a simple count like this.

Suggestions welcome! Thanks.

Comment: You are getting a cursor timeout prolly on that, if you were to run say 10K as you show at time in a loop it should open a new cursor each time and so you shouldn't suffer the timeout problem.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes very easy when you use aggregation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

```
db.collection.aggregate(
     { $unwind : "$items" }, 
     { $group  : {_id:null, items_count : {$sum:1} }}
)
```

to return count of items for each document,

```
{ $group  : {_id:"$_id", items_count : {$sum:1} }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store length of doc.items as an element of doc. This method causes disk redundancy but   a fast and easy way to deal with large collections.

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "itemsLength" : 2,
    "items" : [
       {"key1" : "value1"},
       {"key1" : "value1"}
    ]
}
```

Another option may be using mapreduce but, I think, without sharding mapreduce would be slow.

Comment: The length of "items" is being counted now, but I still need to count those previous documents which don't have it yet.

Comment: You can update previous documents for once, so that all documents will have itemLength property. When all documents have itemLength, you can aggregate with $sum.